# How to print variable value inside a function in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, subprocess

Below is my script in which I am putting value in a `local_server` variable depending on condition in case:

```
#!/bin/bash
servers=(machine981.abc.host.com luck123.pqr.host.com gond654.def.host.com)
case $(hostname -f) in
    *abc.host.com)
        local_server=("${servers[0]}")
        ;;
    *pqr.host.com)
        local_server=("${servers[1]}")
        ;;
    *def.host.com)
        local_server=("${servers[2]}")
        ;;
    *) echo "unknown host: $(hostname -f), exiting." && exit 1 ;;
    # ?
esac

# now this print works fine and it shows right value
echo $local_server

hello() {
  el=$1
  we=$2
  # but this print inside "hello" function doesn't print anything? Why?
  echo $local_server
}
export -f hello

parallel -j 3 hello {} $primary ::: ${pk[@]} &
parallel -j 3 hello {} $secondary ::: ${sk[@]} &
```

Now I have a function `hello()` in which I want to use `local_server` variable but it looks like I can't use it? And it prints empty. What is the reason behind this and how can I print `local_server` variable in `hello` function as well?

Comment: Works for me.  Are you actually *calling* the `hello` function somewhere? It's not in the code in your question.  Also: `h=$(hostname -f); for s in "${servers[@]}"; do [[ $s = *$h ]] && local_server="$s"; done`

Comment: edited my question to show how I am calling it? I am using `gnu-parallel` to call hello function.

Comment: Ah, well, that's kind of vital. `parallel` is not built in to bash, so the contents of the **array** `$local_server` can't be exported. Try just making it a normal variable instead, and don't forget to export it.

Comment: What do you mean by normal variable? I didn't quite understand that. Also example you gave in your first comment is not working in a way - because I need to pick machine from servers list basis on whether I have `abc.host.com` or `def.host.com` or `pqr.host.com`. So if current hostname has `abc.host.com` then I will pick local_server as `machine981.abc.host.com` and similarly for others.

Comment: `variable="value"` assigns a value to `$variable` which is a normal scalar variable. `variable=("value")` assigns a single value to the array `${variable[@]}` which should properly be evaluated with this syntax, and which cannot be exported.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. Export the variable:

```
export local_server
```

or use env_parallel:

```
env_parallel -j 3 hello {} $primary ::: ${pk[@]} &
```

(env_parallel copies even arrays, functions, and aliases - contrary to what you are used to in UNIX).